# kendo chart export pdf using angular

Tags: angularjs, charts, kendo-ui, export-to-pdf

I have kendo scatter line chart using angular. I am trying to add export to pdf but getting error as exportpdf is not a function. Has anyone tried kendo chart exportpdf using angularjs? Here's the example

http://dojo.telerik.com/uMube/8

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you: Instead of `var chart = $scope.chartOptions;` use `var chart = $("#chart").getKendoChart();`.

[Here is the code](http://dojo.telerik.com/uMube/14)

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Put a name into declarative code:

```
<div kendo-chart="michar"...
```

and in your controller put:

```
var chart = $scope.michar
```